# I GET "No database selected" ERROR even that is selected

Tags: php, mysql, crud

Im new in MySql and PHP and im trying to make a CRUD but everytime i try to insert data into table called "studenti" i get the error that i didnt select a database but i selected a database with   mysqli_select_db($con, "d_base");

Somebody please help me cuz i dont understand why its not workin'

Here is the code;

```
$id = $_POST['ID'];
$nota = $_POST['Nota'];
$emri = $_POST['Emri'];
$mbiemri = $_POST['Mbiemri'];



$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "d_base";

// 1.Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","d_base");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO studenti (id, nota, emri, mbiemri) VALUES ('$id', '$nota','$emri','$mbiemri')"))
  {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }

// Perform queries 
mysqli_select_db($con, "d_base");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO studenti (id, nota, emri, mbiemri) VALUES ('$id', '$nota','$emri','$mbiemri')");
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You select it *after* your first query

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: It has to be selected up after you connect, not below

Comment: i selected after the connection but i still get the same error

Comment: Is your database user also d_base? The format for mysqli_connect is `mysqli_connect("db_host", "db_user", "db_password", "db_name");`

Comment: @AlexHowansky he is using mysqli ;) just saying.. But I agree to what you said..

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal My comment was not simply "use mysqli" but "use mysqli prepared statements". Note the link targets.

Comment: yeah; real nice sql injection there. You're not planning on taking this to a live website, *are you?* If you want to keep your website/db intact, then do what @AlexHowansky suggested and read those documents till you know them next to "by heart".

Comment: First you need to connect to your database then you can use querys. `$con = mysqli_connect("host", "database username", "database password", "database name");` and now you have connection and selected database.

Comment: also; what are the POST's origins? Someone gave you an answer below, yet you state it still doesn't work. Ever thought that those may be failing here, or what's being passed through them? Maybe something isn't or mysql is complaining about something but you're not checking for the errors at all. Edit: Oh, you are, you just didn't tell us what those were.

Comment: `(id, nota, emri, mbiemri VALUES` that's a syntax error right there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no im not gonna publish this it's just for learning, thanks for the syntax error i corrected it, but still i get the error

Comment: Bishud Please edit the question if you have corrected the answer as suggested by @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0):

**Before all that if you are a begginer go straight on `PDO` or use `mysqli` with prepared statements its safer.**

Here is example how your php and html form must look like and work.

First you must check if submit button is pressed, if its pressed read values form form `$_POST` variables.

Second thing you must escape injection to your mysql by using function `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

After that try to insert query and check for error, if there is no error query will be inserted successfully.

**PHP code**

```
<?php

// set error report ; 1 = on | 0 = off
error_reporting(1);

$db_host = "localhost"; // host
$db_user = "root";      // database username
$db_pass = "";          // database password
$db_name = "d_base";    // database name

// 1.Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// if form is submited
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // escape post variables
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['ID']);
    $nota = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Nota']);
    $emri = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Emri']);
    $mbiemri = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Mbiemri']);

    // make query
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO studenti (id, nota, emri, mbiemri VALUES ('$id', '$nota', '$emri', '$mbiemri')")

    // check for query
    if (!$query)
    {
        echo "Error description: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Query inserted.";
    }

    // close connenction
    mysqli_close($con);
}


?>

<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="ID" placeholder="Id"><br />
   <input type="text" name="Nota" placeholder="Nota"><br />
   <input type="text" name="Emri" placeholder="Emri"><br />
   <input type="text" name="Mbiemri" placeholder="Mbiemri"><br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

Comment: thank u for the explanation , i just started a few days ago with MySql and PHP

i'v tried this but now i get another error



Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'd_base'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @Bishud probably you are using wrong data for connection to database. You can check yours database user and password in phpmyadmin under **user accounts** tab, here you can see on this image http://image.prntscr.com/image/361edc80d14b4194aa35f91919375508.jpeg

Comment: This is the same thing that I see when I open the user accounts

Comment: @Bishud what is name of yours database and table / column, can you make a image ?

Comment: @Bishud then it must work i will update my code. Put all in 1 script and call it test.php, then run in browser http://localhost/test.php and try it

Comment: This is confusing because i still get the same error. ---- Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'd_base'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Try to reinstall xampp or wamp

Comment: thank u for your help, i just created a new user and its working now.

Comment: @Bishud no problem, i'm glad that you solved problem.